# Constructing SQL Server query from parts in python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-injection

```
Python = 3.10.2
SQLalchemy = 1.4.32
pyodbc = 4.0.32
```

Is it possible to construct sql query from parts and not risk SQL injection? This is what I tried
This function is part of a wrapper class which has engine created

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
    def select_locations(self, country: str, include_neighbours: bool, neighbours: str):
    select_query = text("SELECT * FROM table_a")
    if include_neighbours is False:
        where_query = text("WHERE table_a.country = :country")
    else:
        where_query = text(
            "WHERE table_a.country = :country or table_a.country in (:neighbours)"
        )
    final_query = select_query + where_query

    if include_neighbours is False:
        params = {"country": country}
    else:
        params = {"country": country, "neighbours": neighbours}
    with self.engine.connect() as con:
        result = con.execute(final_query, params).fetchall()
    return result
```

but its not possible to add two text clasues

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TextClause' and 'TextClause'
```

Easiest would be to create a python string but that is risky because of SQL Injection so its out of question. `text` is advisable approach for creating raw sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a query incrementally using SQLAlchemy Core constructs:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

table_a = sa.Table("table_a", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # basic query
    qry = sa.select(sa.text("*")).select_from(table_a)
    results = conn.execute(qry).fetchall()
    """ SQL emitted:
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_a
    
    [generated in 0.00037s] ()
    """

    # add WHERE clause to basic query
    country = "Canada"
    qry = qry.where(table_a.c.country == country)
    results = conn.execute(qry).fetchall()
    """ SQL emitted:
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_a 
    WHERE table_a.country = ?

    [generated in 0.00033s] ('Canada',)
    """
```